# How to install quopri?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.9

I'm currently attempting to install package `quopri` using `pip`, but it's failing with the following errors:

```
:\> pip install --no-cache-dir --verbose pycopy-quopri
Using pip 23.1 from D:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
Collecting pycopy-quopri
  Downloading pycopy-quopri-0.5.1.tar.gz (3.1 kB)
ERROR: pycopy-quopri from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/63/2c7c974f6e57da3ec281297e7afa6d69dc02eef327f9883572447d6e757b/pycopy-quopri-0.5.1.tar.gz does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.

:\> pip -V
pip 23.1 from D:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)
```

I'm able to install other libraries without any problems. Is there an issue with this package? And if so, do you have any suggestions for how I can resolve it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's a module for pycopy, a Python variant - I'm not familiar with it, but apparently its package installation process differs.  You don't need to install anything, anyway, as `quopri` is a built-in module in standard Python.

Comment: Thanks. I was mistaken in my understanding of `quopri` and `pycopy-quopri`. 